# How to get Context of a OnCheckedChangeListener in Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-context

I have 3 radio buttons.I want to save the selected button in Shared preferences.
I am using OnCheckedChangeListener to check which radio button is clicked and saving the button into Shared preferences using context getApplicationContext().However,it throws a Nullpointer exception.

I think the Nullpointer exception is due to incorrect context.Is there any way I can get context of the OnCheckedChangeListener  so that i can save to Shared Preferences.

```
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.userbundle2);


            radioGroup3a = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup3a);
            radioGroup3a.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener1);


    }

        //end of onCreate

    private RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener listener1 = new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

     SharedPreferences preferences2 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(NEED TO PUT CONTEXT HERE);
    //If I put getApplicationContext() it throws a Nullpointer Exception

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences2.edit();
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {


                        if (checkedId != -1) {

            //blah blah
                        }


                        switch (checkedId) {
                            case R.id.radio1:


                            mWeightRange=getResources().getString(R.string.w1);
                            editor.putString(Constants.KEY_WEIGHT_RANGE, mWeightRange).apply();

                            break;

                        case R.id.radio2:
                                break;
                        case R.id.radio3:
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way I can get context of the OnCheckedChangeListener

A listener does not have a `Context`.

Move your `SharedPreferences preferences2` and `SharedPreferences.Editor editor` to be local variables inside of `onCheckedChanged()`. You can call `getContext()` on the `RadioGroup` to get a `Context` to use with `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()`.

Comment: Thanks.There was a fundamental issue with the way I think of contexts...

If I move the preference& Editor locally,I can't use getContext() (cant resolve method getcontext() ).I am doing something wrong.

Comment: @Michel: I assure you that [there is a `getContext()` method on `RadioGroup`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext()), inherited from the base `View` class.